# Prevent html input type=number from ever being empty

Tags: html, input

I know HTML 5 allows for input of type `number` where it only allows the user to enter inputs of type digits. When my page loads I set my default input to 0 but the user can just erase this value so that when the user hits submit a blank input (null) is submitted?  Is there a way so that when the user erases all numbers in the input the value defaults back to 0? I'm not talking about validation here.

Trying to avoid an ugly JS hack but if that's the only way then I guess I'll have to go that route.

Comment: So add validation. Make it required.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

HTML5 validation rules will only help when the form is submitted. If you want to prevent the input from being empty you'll need to use some JS.

The following (not "ugly JS hack") will work for all `number` inputs on a page and insert a value of `0` if the user tries to leave the input empty.

```js
const numInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]')

numInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.value == '') {
      e.target.value = 0
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="number" required value="0" />

<input type="number" required value="0" />
```

Comment: I think you're right I'm not seeing any other way. This should be a built in attribute

Comment: Thank you very much! Does exactly what I need it to!

Answer (score 16):

So use [HTML5 validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation). Will not submit unless it is valid.

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="num">Pick a number?</label>
  <input id="num" name="number" type="number" value="0" min="0" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great answer! Although I'm trying to prevent the user from ever having a blank input in the first place which as Brett pointed out in his answer above is not possible without js.

Comment: Or you handle it on the code that sets a default when there is no value set. That is what I would do. I would not rely on JavaScript to set a default.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do it with JQuery; here is it:

```
<input type="number" class="minZero" />

  $(".minZero").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(0);
        } 
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this in React with a controlled input and setting a State (or in many other similar applicable cases), you can reference the **valueAsNumber**, and if the user tries to enter a blank value (NaN), that will be falsy, so then use an OR 0. Like this:

```
onChange={(event) => setStateNamedValue(event.target.valueAsNumber || 0)}
```

This then won't allow a blank value - it will send a zero instead.